# Get PayPal Access token in Lollipop

Tags: android, paypal, bluetooth, token

So I am trying to make an app for users to swipe their credit card and it will bluetooth to a device to handle it. I am using the PayPal SDK but i cant seem to figure out how to get the Access Token to use for my request. Here is my current code:

```
    public String performPostCall(String requestURL, HashMap<String, String> postDataParams) {

    URL url;
    String response = "";
    try {
        url = new URL(requestURL);

        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setReadTimeout(15000);
        conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setDoInput(true);
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");


        OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
                new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
        writer.write(getPostDataString(postDataParams));

        writer.flush();
        writer.close();
        os.close();
        int responseCode=conn.getResponseCode();

        if (responseCode == HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            String line;
            BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
            while ((line=br.readLine()) != null) {
                response+=line;
            }
        }
        else {
            response="";

        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return response;
}

private String getPostDataString(HashMap<String, String> params) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    boolean first = true;
    for(Map.Entry<String, String> entry : params.entrySet()){
        if (first)
            first = false;
        else
            result.append("&");

        result.append(URLEncoder.encode(entry.getKey(), "UTF-8"));
        result.append("=");
        result.append(URLEncoder.encode(entry.getValue(), "UTF-8"));
    }

    return result.toString();
}

public String getPaypalToken() {
    HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
    String CLIENT_ID = "no";
    String SECRET = "no";
    params.put("username", Base64.encodeToString((CLIENT_ID + ":" + SECRET).getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT));
    params.put("grant_type", "client_credentials");
    System.out.println("Params: " + params);
    String output = performPostCall("https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token", params);
    System.out.println("Output: " + output);
    return output;
}
```

I know its really unsafe to put the `client_id` and `secret` in the Android device itself but the only place this app is going is my device. PayPal is returning nothing, and I have no clue why. If anyone could give me some pointers or maybe even some code that would be very nice. :)